# Getting big endian linux build to boot on ARM with u-boot

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, u-boot, cubieboard

I’m trying to make a big endian build of a linux distribution for ARM. Since I’m on Gentoo, cross-compiling couldn’t be easier. I’ve already built it all, but then got stuck with getting it/the kernel to boot.

I’m targetting Cubieboard with AllWinner A10 CPU. As a bootloader I use u-boot. Since u-boot doesn’t support big endian ARM, I patched it exactly before passing control to the kernel:

```
diff -Naur u-boot-2016.01-1/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c u-boot-2016.01-2/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c
--- u-boot-2016.01-1/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c       2016-01-12 15:06:54.000000000 +0100
+++ u-boot-2016.01-2/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c       2017-07-09 14:13:29.675865446 +0200
@@ -315,7 +315,16 @@
                                                          0, machid, r2);
                } else
 #endif
+               {
+                       {
+                               unsigned long v;
+                               __asm volatile ("mrc p15, 0, %0, c1, c0, 0\n\t"
+                                               "orr %0, %0, #(1 << 7)\n\t" /* Switch to bigendian */
+                                               "mcr p15, 0, %0, c1, c0, 0" : "=&r" (v));
+                       }
+
                        kernel_entry(0, machid, r2);
+               }
        }
 #endif
 }
```

I originally used a little different syntax, but in the end took a known-to-work code from APEX boot loader (its arm-kernel-shim). (Nonetheless, the register is the same as what I had and what I read in ARM documentation.)

Also, since u-boot needs to be little endian, I prepared another toolchain for it—with target `arm-linux-gnueabihf`. As far as I can tell, u-boot itself boots fine.

The (mainline) kernel is compiled with a toolchain for target `armeb-linux-gnueabihf`. From the compiled image (`arch/arm/boot/Image` within kernel source/build tree) I built a bootable image (using `mkimage` from my u-boot build):

```
mkimage -C none -A arm -T kernel -n Linux-4.9.9-gentoo -d /usr/armeb-linux-gnueabihf/usr/src/linux/arch/arm/boot/Image -ep 0x48000000 -a 0x48000000 /usr/armeb-linux-gnueabihf/boot/uimage
```

I took the DTB file also from kernel:

```
cp /usr/armeb-linux-gnueabihf/usr/src/linux/arch/arm/boot/dts/sun4i-a10-cubieboard.dtb /usr/armeb-linux-gnueabihf/boot/
```

When I load it all up to µSD card and try to boot, I get the following output on serial console:

```
U-Boot SPL 2016.01 (Jul 16 2017 - 13:52:00)
DRAM: 1024 MiB
CPU: 1008000000Hz, AXI/AHB/APB: 3/2/2
Trying to boot from MMC


U-Boot 2016.01 (Jul 16 2017 - 13:52:00 +0200) Allwinner Technology

CPU:   Allwinner A10 (SUN4I)
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  1 GiB
MMC:   SUNXI SD/MMC: 0
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
SCSI:  SUNXI SCSI INIT
SATA link 0 timeout.
AHCI 0001.0100 32 slots 1 ports 3 Gbps 0x1 impl SATA mode
flags: ncq stag pm led clo only pmp pio slum part ccc apst
Net:   eth0: ethernet@01c0b000
starting USB...
USB0:   USB EHCI 1.00
USB1:   USB OHCI 1.0
USB2:   USB EHCI 1.00
USB3:   USB OHCI 1.0
scanning bus 0 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
scanning bus 2 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
=> setenv bootargs console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200 earlyprintk hdmi.audio=EDID:0 disp.screen0_output_mode=EDID:1280x800p60 root=PARTUUID=AC9D6C6F-01 rootwait panic=10
=> ext2load mmc 0 0x48000000 boot/uimage
5025856 bytes read in 592 ms (8.1 MiB/s)
=> ext2load mmc 0 0x51000000 boot/sun4i-a10-cubieboard.dtb
28542 bytes read in 237 ms (117.2 KiB/s)
=> bootm 0x48000000 - 0x51000000
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 48000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-4.9.9-gentoo
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    5025792 Bytes = 4.8 MiB
   Load Address: 48000000
   Entry Point:  48000000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 51000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x51000000
   Loading Kernel Image ... OK
   Loading Device Tree to 49ff6000, end 49ffff7d ... OK

Starting kernel ...
```

And it just hangs there like this – no progress, no output, nothing. My question is, how to proceed from here/how to find out what is actually happening? Am I missing something, did I do anything wrong (or didn’t do something)?

Some more things I tried, but without success:

- word-swapping the kernel image (as APEX does) (resulted in `undefined instruction` on boot),
- using compressed kernel image,
- using legacy FEX file instead of FDT.

---

Update 2017/07/21: I’ve been partly successful in solving my issue. I took the hint from Tom Rini’s comment and tried packing zImage into the uImage which made the kernel boot. With a custom init program (just a simple Hello World compiled either BE or LE) I confirmed the other Tom Rini’s suspicion: my original kernel was not big endian, but little. To fix this, I added the following two lines to the top of kernel’s `.config`:

```
CONFIG_ARCH_SUPPORTS_BIG_ENDIAN=y
CONFIG_CPU_BIG_ENDIAN=y
```

I sourced my inspiration from a [how-to for Nvidia Jetson TK1](http://wiki.baserock.org/How_to_install_a_big-endian_Linux_system_to_NVIDIA_Jetson_TK1/). I also added the following line to `arch/arm/mach-sunxi/Kconfig` at the end of A10 section:

```
select ARCH_SUPPORTS_BIG_ENDIAN
```

It turned out that this is enough to build and boot a big endian kernel as the kernel itself switches the CPU to big endian mode. However, it does so with `setend` instruction---its scope is only for the kernel itself, not for userspace (as link in Murray Jensen’s answer explains).

I’m going to try:

- jumping to kernel’s decompressor entry point via exception, or (if I fail)
- patching the kernel so that it spawns processes into big endian settings (although I sort of smell a minefield there...).

Comment: Did you confirm that the resulting zImage is big endian?  And please note that uImages are made from the zImage, not Image, see arch/arm/boot/Makefile in the kernel for more details.

Comment: Would the FDT blob need to be big endian also? or is the endianness of this fixed by a standard somewhere? (where?)

Comment: @TomRini Thank you, this has been very helpful! I thought the kernel is BE since I compiled it with BE compiler, but it apparently wasn’t enough. I [found a page](http://wiki.baserock.org/How_to_install_a_big-endian_Linux_system_to_NVIDIA_Jetson_TK1/) that describes compiling BE kernel for a different platform and used hints from there. Also, I tried zImage previously, but failed, still I gave it a try again now. And now I boot BE. :-) What I can’t yet, is to run the userspace (`Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b`), but it’s already a great progress!

Comment: @MurrayJensen It seems like it’s either fixed or the kernel can handle both. What I can say is that the FDT blob didn’t recompile when I forced the kernel into BE mode. And both LE and BE kernels boot with the same version of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know a lot about ARM (yet), but according to [this](https://community.arm.com/processors/f/discussions/3313/how-and-where-do-i-change-endianness-in-cortex-a9), *"The EE bit in the CP15 System Control Register (SCR) determines the endianness set on exception (i.e. the endianness of the OS itself)."* ... so it seems to me that you need to enter the loaded kernel image via an exception somehow i.e. you can't just jump to the address (as U-Boot appears to do - see `boot_jump_linux()` in [this](https://github.com/u-boot/u-boot/blob/master/arch/arm/lib/bootm.c)).

Comment: Note that the zImage/uImage doesn't start the kernel itself, rather it starts the decompression wrapper that in turn starts the kernel.  That, however never starts in this case.

Comment: Yes, so the decompression wrapper would need to be big endian also ... and you would have to jump to it via an exception after setting the EE bit.